# how to get value from document.getelementbyid in c sharp

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to pass the element's value into a controller

**JavaScript:**

```
var element = document.getElementById("valueSelected");
```

Comment: you want to pass the "valueSelected" element value to controller function?

Comment: You can use ajax to do that

Comment: @Saadi, yes without using a razor stuff

Comment: ok. check my answer. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let suppose Home is your Controller.

Add a function in your controller who can handle your ajax request. Suppose function name is getValue:

```
public void GetValue(string elementValue)
{
    //add your controller logic here
}
```

In your javascript, I use jquery to perform ajax request, you need to jquery to do this so:

```
var element = document.getElementById("valueSelected");
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data : { elementValue : $(element).val() },
     url: '@Url.Action("GetValue", "Home")'
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Query String

```
Document.location="/ControllerName/ActionName/Value";
```

Ajax

```
$.Post('/ControllerName/ActionName/',{Parameter: element});
```

Comment: Thank you so mush but how to get that value in my controller ? .... i'm so sorry but it's just because i'm newest with c sharp

Answer (score 1):

No problem

Script

```
function Delete() {
    $.getJSON("/ControllerName/ActionName/", {Id : Value}, function (data) 
       {
          alert(data)
       })
};
```

C#

```
public JsonResult ActionName(int? id)
    {
        string Data = "Sample Data";
        return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Good one ! Choukran jazilan @Ahmad